# SQL Server script to find LOB columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Looking for a script to scan all tables in all SQL Server databases and list the columns which are large objects (TEXT, NTEXT, ,IMAGE VARCHAR(MAX), NVARCHAR(MAX), FILESTREAM, XML, VARBINARY).

while I probably can code this myself, I want a ready made script.

Comment: Did you mean to tag it as 2008, as Filestream isn't available in 2005.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 select * from information_schema.columns where data_type in 
    ('TEXT', 'NTEXT','IMAGE' ,'XML', 'VARBINARY')
    or 
    (data_type = 'VARCHAR' and character_maximum_length = -1)
    OR
    (data_type = 'NVARCHAR' and character_maximum_length = -1)
```

**Update** Removed FILESTREAM from IN since the data_type is VARBINARY which is already captured

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where DATA_TYPE in('text','ntext','xml','image')
or  (DATA_TYPE in('varchar','nvarchar','varbinary')
and CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1)
order by DATA_TYPE
```

filestream is stored as varbinary(max)

This will only capture varbinary(max), not varbinary(20) for example, if you also want that then move varbinary to the first condition, like this

```
 select * from information_schema.columns
    where DATA_TYPE in('text','ntext','xml','image','varbinary')
    or  (DATA_TYPE in('varchar','nvarchar')
    and CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1)
    order by DATA_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.table_schema,
    t.table_name, 
    c.COLUMN_NAME,c.data_type 
from information_schema.columns c
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t
        on c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        and c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
and ((c.data_type in ('VARCHAR', 'NVARCHAR') and c.character_maximum_length = -1)
or data_type in ('TEXT', 'NTEXT', 'IMAGE', 'VARBINARY', 'XML', 'FILESTREAM'))
group by t.table_schema, 
    t.table_name, c.COLUMN_NAME,c.data_type 
order by t.table_schema, 
    t.table_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).